# How to integrate richfaces 4.3 (a4j) in JSF2 Enterprise Application

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am getting following Warning when trying to integrate Richfaces in JSF2 Project.

```
Warning: The page /template/template.xhtml declares namespace http://richfaces.org/a4j and uses the tag a4j:region , but no TagLibrary associated to namespace.
```

I am not using maven so i made everything manually.
I made following things to integrate it: 
Put in EAR Deployment Assembly following jars:

```
richfaces-components-api-4.3.0.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.3.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.3.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.3.0.Final.jar
sac-1.3.jar 
guava-11.0.2.jar 
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
```

Added it to WAR's Manifest.

Here is Page-Snippet:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    id="TemplateView">
   ...
    <h:form id="templateForm">
        <a4j:region>
            <a4j:jsFunction name="refreshSession">
                <a4j:actionparam name="refresh" assignTo="#{ilapAdapter.refreshSession}"/>
            </a4j:jsFunction>
        </a4j:region>
    </h:form>
   ...
```

Am I missing something? Why I am getting this warning? According to "Getting Started" Guide there is no need of additional configuration in faces-config.xml or web.xml.

I need only Ajax functionality of Richfaces.

PS. Placing richfaces-core-api-4.3.0.Final.jar, richfaces-core-impl-4.3.0.Final.jar in WEB-INF.lib is not working either.

Richfaces relevant SystemOut:

```
[08.02.13 14:18:26:398 CET] 00000022 DefaultFacesC I   Reading config : wsjar:file:/C:/projects/folab/workspace/FOLAB-WAS8/installedApps/CE02110Node02Cell/Dialog_Common_EAR.ear/richfaces-core-impl-4.3.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
[08.02.13 14:18:26:949 CET] 00000022 Config        W org.richfaces.application.DefaultModule configure There was no service org.richfaces.focus.FocusManager found
[08.02.13 14:18:26:956 CET] 00000022 Cache         I org.richfaces.cache.CacheManager getCacheFactory Selected fallback cache factory
[08.02.13 14:18:26:959 CET] 00000022 Cache         I org.richfaces.cache.lru.LRUMapCacheFactory createCache Creating LRUMap cache instance using parameters: {com.ibm.ws.jsf.JSP_UPDATE_CHECK=true, javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD=server, javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE=Development, com.ibm.ws.jsf.LOAD_FACES_CONFIG_AT_STARTUP=true, javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES=/WEB-INF/faces-navigation.xml, javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX=.xhtml}
[08.02.13 14:18:26:969 CET] 00000022 Cache         I org.richfaces.cache.lru.LRUMapCacheFactory createCache Creating LRUMap cache instance of 512 items capacity
[08.02.13 14:18:26:985 CET] 00000022 Application   I org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener onStart  by , version 
[08.02.13 14:18:26:989 CET] 00000022 Application   W org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener logWarningWhenConnectionFactoryPresent JMS API was found on the classpath; if you want to enable RichFaces Push JMS integration, set context-param 'org.richfaces.push.jms.enabled' in web.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!

Problem was wrong myfaces implementation. Richfaces 4.3 requires at least myfaces 2.1.5 I have been using 2.0.8. Somehow I missed this information when Reading requirements for the first time.

Second problem was lack of richfaces-components-ui-4.3.0.Final.jar (however according to readme and dev guide it was not required for a4j).
Hope it helps someone in future.